# passing 2D char arrays without known size (row and column) in C++17

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

Currently, I'm working on creating matrices for cryptography projects. However, I'm having an issue when trying to pass a matrix to a function without having the size for the rows and columns.

Summary of code:

In main, I create an instance of a Cipher class, I'm allowed to get an input file (plaintext) and a key (key is used for enc/decryption).

Then, in `Cipher.cpp`, I do the blocks for the class functions. For this question, I'll focus on encryption function.

Inside of it, I initialized a `char matrix[plaintext.size()][keySize]`.

Now, because of modularity, I want to pass this matrix by reference to a function that generates the matrix. This is the issue, I cannot pass the matrix with two variables (`plaintextSize`, `keySize`), I can only pass it with constant values (e.g `char (&matrix)[5][5]`).

I've also tried passing like `char* matrix`, but that obviously doesn't work. This issue leaves me with an encryption function that does two different things: generating the matrix and doing the actual encryption, which is something I don't want.

Any help will be appreciated it.

Comment: Easiest way would be to use a single-dimension vector instead of multi-dimensional matrices. You can always translate access with two dimensions into a single-dimension access based on offset. Than represent this as either `std::vector` or `std::array` and pass this to your function (likely by reference)

Comment: "something I don't want" -- Why not? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: "... but that obviously doesn't work" it isnt obvious. Passing a `char*` is fine in principle. Better show your code ([mcve]) instead of describing it. What is obvious to you isnt obvious to others and vice versa

Comment: I've heard the term black box used to describe desired function behavior. Basically, seeing the signature and maybe a descriptive comment should make it very clear what the function's purpose is, and you don't have to care *how* it goes about its business. Also the standalone nature of a free function, i.e., not relying on variables outside the scope (globals, etc.).

Comment: Thank you @SergeA. What I did was declare the vector (vector<vector<char>> matrix, then I passed it to GenerateMatrix by reference, with size of rows, columns, and the plaintext as additional paramaters. Then inside GenerateMatrix, I resized it (resize()), and then I filled it up with the chars of the plaintext. It works, and now I have two functions that are in charge of only aspect of the program.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this in one of two basic ways:

1. you can pass a vector of vectors
2. you can pass a char * plus the
   rows and columns and do your own math

   int foo(char *array, int numRows, int numCols) {
   int row = 4;
   int col = 3;
   int index = row * numCols + col;
   cout << row << ", " << col << " == " << array[index] << endl;
   }

It's kind of ugly, though.

Comment: Just say no to *vector of vectors*. Goodbye forever, vectors of vectors.

Comment: @SergeyA I look forward to your better answer.

Comment: @JosephLarson, I think I did 1, vector<vector<char>>, thank you anyways for the help.